# Using C++ in virtual PBDA driver: what are the limitations?

Tags: c++, kernel, driver, wdm

Im planing to integrate an existing C++ project (which provides transport stream data) into a virtual DVB driver under Windows7. The obvious starting point appears to be the SW Tuner sample from the Microsoft WDK (version 7600.16385.1). This sample provided by Microsoft already implements a virtual PBDA driver, which reads transport stream data from local files.

Now my question is: What features of C++ are (or are not) available in a kernel driver?

I've read the Microsoft page ["C++ for Kernel Mode Drivers: Pros and Cons"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487420.aspx), and it appears to be generally possible to use basic C++ in kernel drivers? While it is understandable that Microsoft doesn't give very precise guarantees, the text left me somewhat puzzled about what actually was possible using C++ three years ago, or even today.

Can STL can be used in Kernel Drivers?
(From looking at the WDK: There are flags like "USE_STL" or "STL_VER", and two directories STL60 and STL70 in the WDK path. The discussion threads I could find where somewhat inconclusive. I managed to get the SWTuner sample to build with "USE_STL=1", but didn't do any further tests on that yet.).
Can STL containers be used to manage memory in a kernel driver?

Are C++ exceptions available?
From what I could find (f.e. at ["Drivers, Exceptions and C++"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/excpt.aspx?msg=2935233)), it appears to be generally possible to use C++ exceptions (try/throw/catch) since they are mapped to SEH, but still require some fiddling with workarounds?

Would multi-threading code work in kernel space?

The general design decision I'm trying to make as a driver newbie is: Would it be more feasible to integrate the C++ project into the existing sample (which would save a lot of hassle with interfaces, but comes with the "C++ in kernel driver" baggage), or would it be more prudent to encapsulate the C++ project in an application, which then communicates with the virtual driver via interfaces that would yet have to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a virtual printer driver using the DDK (the newer versions are called DDK instead of WDK I think), and I had no problem using STL.